# How to automate this as a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates, chess

I am trying to make a chess board with draggable pieces using jquery where the pieces snap to the new destination square. I have been experimenting with a variety of concepts but I have not been able to make anything I try work.

I believe I'm missing some fundamental concepts.

I have written some code that loads a few pieces on a board and makes them draggable, but I haven't been able to figure out how to define the grid without manual math. I can place the pieces after using the below manual system.It seems like an excellent candidate for a for loop and a multidimensional array. I would ultimately like to say that

`a1 = [0+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%"], a2 = [0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"]`

so I can later use algebraic notation, etc. for all ranks and files.

```
function initCoords(){

var aFile = [[0+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((7/8)*100)+"%"]];

var bFile = [[0+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((6/8)*100)+"%"]];

var cFile = [[0+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((5/8)*100)+"%"]];

var dFile = [[0+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((4/8)*100)+"%"]];

var eFile = [[0+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((3/8)*100)+"%"]];

var fFile = [[0+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((2/8)*100)+"%"]];

var gFile = [[0+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((1/8)*100)+"%"]];

var hFile = [[0+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((3/8)*100)+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((4/8)*100)+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((5/8)*100)+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((6/8)*100)+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"],[0+((7/8)*100)+"%",0+((0/8)*100)+"%"]];

}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you find another way to do this! Your current method appears to very tightly bind the "Model" of the chess board with the graphical representation...

Comment: I agree, even your ultimate goal is simply a big `WTF` for me. Use abstractions.

Comment: El Ronnoco, this is why I'm here asking!

Comment: Okay, phant0m -- Simply: i want a chess board that initializes pieces in the correct positions, that are draggable, that snap to the square the mouse is over. The code I posted is how I was able to get the pieces in the right positions. But there must be a way to automate all the math! and there must be a way to iterate through the alphabet for a-h for a variable name? [a]file, [g]file? Or there must be some other ideas I'm missing altogether?

Comment: Have you consider having a look at jQuery UI, like Draggable and Droppable?

Comment: For one thing, computers don't naturally iterate over letters, they iterate over numbers ;) The computer doesn't care about Rank A or B - just call them 0 and 1 and make your life a whole lot easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with other posters about separating your logical and graphical view, but I'd like to answer your question as presented, as it should help you think about finding commonality in your code that you can factor out.

When trying to automate the creation of a dataset like this, you need to look for commonalities and sequences.  As you do that, you should be able to iterate towards a decent solution.

For a start, rather than having a set of variables called xFile (where x is a-h), why not create an object called "Files", with properties a-h, thus:

```
files = {
  a:[],
  b:[],
  ...
}
```

Even that may be more complex than you need - for ease of creation, you may find that you want a 2D array, where a=0, b=1 etc. is much easier to deal with (though see below, h=0, g=1... is even easier).

So, the next obvious commonality is that the first cell in each of the arrays you present follows the same pattern: `[0+"%",0+((n/8)*100)+"%"]`, where `n` is 7->0 going from a-h.  So you could easily generate each of the first cells thus:

```
files = [];
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    files[Math.abs(i-7)] = [0+"%",0+((i/8)*100)+"%"]
}
```

Now, this is a little ugly, the Math.abs call there is because the numbers increase in the opposite direction to the array.  There are other ways to do this, but IMO they are all pretty ugly. Instead, you could consider inverting the order of the array, so that it runs h-a, rather than a-h:

```
files = [];
for (n = 0; n <= 7; n += 1) {
    files[n] = [0+"%",0+((n/8)*100)+"%"]
}
```

OK, so having seen this commonality, you can look at the next cells.  These are all the same `[0+((1/8)*100)+"%",0+((n/8)*100)+"%"]` for the second, and `[0+((2/8)*100)+"%",0+((n/8)*100)+"%"]` for the third, both where where `n` is 0-7 for a-h.

Actually, we see another commonality here:
They could both be described as `[0+((j/8)*100)+"%",0+((i/8)*100)+"%"]` where `i` is the `n` from before, and `j` is the rank (1-7).

Even more, the difference between cell 0 and cells 1-7 is that cells 1-7 all start with `0+((i/8)*100)+`, whereas cell 0 just starts with `0+`.  But what is `((0/8)*100)`? It's `0`!

So, there are no special cases, each cell can be defined as `[0+((j/8)*100)+"%",0+((i/8)*100)+"%"]`

So, taking the loop from before, we can extend it with an inner loop, thus:

```
files = [];
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i += 1) {
    files[i] = []
    for (j = 0; j <=7; j += 1) {
        files[i][j] = [0+((j/8)*100)+"%",0+((i/8)*100)+"%"]
    }
}
```

The above code is untested so I don't discount having made some error, but it *should* generate an array with the data you present above, (though running from h-a rather than a-h)

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Now I understand why I couldn't get variable properties working in a for loop. I wasn't declaring the variable and properties first! And the additional information you provided is great! I will have to study your post a bit and experiment. Of course, I will be taking into account separating logic and graphicals as well. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this a "nasty" way!

You can represent the chess board with an array such as

```
var board = [];  //make a new array

//push 8 new arrays of length 8 onto this board array - ie 8 x 8
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) board.push(new Array(8));
```

Each location within this array can store any Javascript object - I would suggest starting with some simple way of representing a piece.

You need to separate the graphical components from the logical representation of the board - which I don't feel you are currently doing.

Perhaps have a class such as....

```
function piece(col, typ) {
    var colour = col, 
        pieceType = typ;

    return {
        colour : colour,
        pieceType : typ
    }
}
```

Then you can say...

```
board[0][4] = new piece('white','queen');
```

..for instance.

Try encoding game logic in the classes eg Can you have a Blue Queen? Can you have a White Cow? Can a White King jump? etc etc

You will find your code gets nicer to read as you do more refactoring.

And don't write such long lines of code!! It's a sure sign something needs rethinking!

Have fun! :)

Comment: Thank you El Ronnoco. My next question will likely be how to link the graphical and logical. But I've read enough about that over the past couple of weeks that I may figure it out on my own. I think you nailed it.. I'm confusing two separate ideas.

Comment: No worries - there are (literally) millions of different ways you could write a chess program - and that's before you start thinking about having the comp actually play. I'm sure you can find lots of inspiration on the net about how to separation presentation from model.